# Leaflet marker disable hover or show nothing on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, leaflet, marker

I am using Leaflet API to draw some markers on the map. My marker data is populated using HTML which displays fine when clicked on. The problem is when hovered on top of the marker it displays the html tags also. 
Either I want to disable the hover entirely OR show the data only on hover also excluding the Html tags OR show empty string on hover which ever is easier.

My code (JS):

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     var a = arr[i];
     var title = a[2];

     var marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), { title: title });
     marker.bindPopup(title);
     layer.markers.addLayer(marker);
}

map.addLayer(layer.markers);
```

Comment: It's not the default behaviour. Hovering on a marker should not do anything. Can you provide a page or a JSFiddle to show this ?

Comment: The default behaviour on hover over a marker is it shows the contents inside the marker. However I have html tags which i do not want to display

Comment: I have figured out its the tooltip that is displaying - any way of disabling it for the markers

Comment: sorry I missed you title option. See answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the option title

```
var marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]));
```

instead of

```
var marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), { title: title });
```

Ref: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker